# Develop application on windows phone device?

Tags: windows-phone-7, licensing, app-hub

I am developing an application for the windows phone platform.

I ve never developed before for this platform so i am not familiar with the process i need to follow in order to be able to develop on the device.

Supposedly my email address , should be registered in a developing license from my company.

I registered as a developer on the [Windows Phone Dev Center](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us) with my mail , i download Zune , i made an account there and my phone is recognized on Zune.

Now i am trying to register the phone with the windows phone developer registration tool but i am getting the error: `device not registered with marketplace. please return to the app hub for more information`

Is there something more i should do? I am an iOS developer , and there is a section in my developers account page , where i can see in what developing programs i can participate , see my provision profiles etc.

Where is this section for the windows platform?

The only thing i see is the `Join now` section where it asks me to create an account type of `Company` or `Student/Individual`.  But these options are to get a developing license on my own.

Shouldnt i have a license already connected with this email address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You have to set up a Microsoft account in the device also.

In other words, in the device go to settings -- > Select 'Email + accounts' --> Add an account --> select 'Microsoft account'

then enter your email id and other details

To check if this process is successful, download any free app from Marketplace.

And one more thing, What do you mean by "I registered as a developer on the Windows Phone Dev Center with my mail" ? Did you pay $99 ?

Go to this link [Dev dashboard](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/dashboard), if you see Join Now .. you did not get a license yet.

Comment: I mean i created an account so that i could sign in https://dev.windowsphone.com .  Yes i see the Join Now license. So that means they havent connected my account with the license? I didnt pay for anything. I though that this mail account should be connected already to the companies license

Comment: I am not sure about your company license, please check that with your company people. All that I can say is, you dont have a license yet for your mail id.

Comment: actually i had to create a dreamspark account , but i ll accept your answer for all the helpful details :)